# Diffie-Hellman insecure on addition modulo $n$

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory

Assume that the group $G$ is the set $\mathbb{Z}_{n} = \{0,\ldots, n-1\}$ for a 1024 bit integer and $+$ is addition modulo $n$. Then why would Diffie-Hellman key exchange in this group be insecure?

Comment: Because the discrete logarithm problem in $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$ is easy. You may look at [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11657/can-anyone-give-an-example-where-asymmetric-crypto-can-go-wrong-due-to-selecti/11669#11669).

Answer (score 5):

With addition and $\mathbb{Z}_n$, each party chooses a secret $x$ and sends $xg \pmod n$ over the wire, for an agreed upon generator $g$. Division by $g$ modulo $n$ is easily computable, and reveals $x$.

In other words, a prerequisite for DH to be secure is that the equivalent to [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) is hard in the chosen group. With $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and addition, discrete logarithm becomes totally easy.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which allows us to compute inverses modulo any number. If the modulus is prime, things are even more easier to explain.

For prime $p$, we know that $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Therefore, $y = g^{p-2} \equiv 1/g \pmod {p}$.

Therefore, $(xg).y \equiv x \pmod{p}$, revealing the secret key.

If modulus is not prime and factors are unknown, then $y$ can be computed using the extended Euclidean algorithm, which has complexity $O(\log{n})$ for modulus $n$.